# Tabulator - direct data for first page combined with ajaxScroll possible?

Tags: tabulator

I want to combine direct data for first page with ajax on scroll, so that the table with data is show as soon the page is loaded and there is no delay for first ajax request, like this:

```
new Tabulator({
  data: [...],
  ajaxUrl: ....,
  ajaxProgressiveLoad:'scroll', ...
```

When I do this the data is shown, but there is no progressive load on scroll. Only when I change sort with tableHeaders or invoke table.setData() in the console, data is reloaded via ajax and then scroll works. Is there a way to have ajax-scroll working with first batch of non-ajax data?

Comment: Idea: this might be implementable without declaring data:[...] but with overriding ajaxRequestFunc and returning the first batch from array, later batches via ajax.

Comment: Thats exactly what I would do, implement your own loading functions